# Saving RGBA image with PIL.Image.frombuffer()

Tags: python, buffer, python-imaging-library, raspberry-pi3, rgba

I need to save a transparent image made from a numpy array. I can save the image with:

```
img = Image.fromarray(data, 'RGB')
```

But I need it to be transparent so I tried to save it with :

```
img = Image.fromarray(data, 'RGBA')
```

Then I get this error :

```
File "/home/pi/Documents/Projet/GetPos.py", line 51, in click
 img = Image.fromarray(data, 'RGBA')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2217, in 
fromarray
 return frombuffer(mode, size, obj, "raw", rawmode, 0, 1)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2162, in 
frombuffer
 core.map_buffer(data, size, decoder_name, None, 0, args)
ValueError: buffer is not large enough
```

I made some research but everythings looks very complicated for the simple thing I'm trying to do... 
Does anyone can help me on this one ?

Here's my complete code ( I'm pretty new to python :) ):

```
mouse = pymouse.PyMouse()
posX, posY = mouse.position()
print(mouse.position())

w, h = 1920, 1080
data = np.zeros((h, w, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

for x in range(posX-20, posX+20):
    if x > 1679:
        data[posY, w-1] = [255, 0, 0]
    else:
        data[posY, x] = [255, 0, 0]

for y in range(posY-20, posY+20):
    if y > 1049:
        data[h-1, posX] = [255, 0, 0]
    else:
        data[y, posX] = [255, 0, 0]

img = Image.fromarray(data, 'RGBA')            
##img = Image.frombuffer('RGBA', [1080, 1920], data, "raw", 'RGBA', 0, 1)
img.save('my.png')
```

Answer (score 5):

In order to save a transparant image, you need to have a fourth value per pixel called the alpha channel, which determines the opacity of your pixel. (RGBA stands for red, green, blue and alpha.) So the only thing that has to be changed in your code is essentialy providing that 4th alpha value using tuples of 4 values instead of 3 for a pixel. Setting the 4th value to 255 means it's completely visible, 0 would make it a 100% transparant. In the following example I simply set every pixel that you were drawing red completely visible, the others will be transparent:

```
mouse = pymouse.PyMouse()
posX, posY = mouse.position()

w, h = 1920, 1080
data = np.zeros((h, w, 4), dtype=np.uint8)

for x in range(posX-20, posX+20):
if x > 1679:
    data[posY, w-1] = [255, 0, 0, 255]
else:
    data[posY, x] = [255, 0, 0, 255]

for y in range(posY-20, posY+20):
    if y > 1049:
        data[h-1, posX] = [255, 0, 0, 255]
    else:
        data[y, posX] = [255, 0, 0, 255]

img = Image.fromarray(data, 'RGBA')            
img.save('my.png')
```